# Flask - using outputs from a function inside another Function

Tags: python, flask

If I define two functions:

```
def atesting():
    a = 2
    return a

def btesting():
    b = a+ 3
    return b
```

But in Flask I get an "Internal Server Error" when running the following if "a" hasn't been defined already. Although if I define "a" outside the app ie say a =2, then it works and I get 5.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    results = {}

    a = atesting()

    results = btesting()

    return render_template('index.html', results=results)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Index.html:

```
<html>

      <h1>{{ results }}</h1>

</html>
```

But just normally in Python I get 5 when i run this:

```
a = atesting()
btesting()
```

Why won't Flask use a = atesting() as an input when computing btesting()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flask error is correct.

For this usecase there is no global **a**. (It is set inside the *index* function, so other functions can't see it)

This is different, if you define a globally in a 
normal program.

If you want to let function btesting seen the a variable,
pass it as a parameter.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    results = {}

    a = atesting()

    results = btesting(a)

    return render_template('index.html', results=results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and

```
def btesting(a):
    b = a + 3
    return b
```

Comment: Thank's for such a quick response, I was stuck on it for so long and you literally solved it in 2 minutes! Works perfectly, and makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it written, `btesting` cannot see `a`. You need to understand *scope*. Try this for your functions - note that we are telling `btesting` the value of `a` by passing it as an argument:

```
def atesting():
    a = 2
    return a

def btesting(a):
    b = a+ 3
    return b
```

Then, call it like this (pass the value to the function)

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    results = {}

    a = atesting()

    results = btesting(a)

    return render_template('index.html', results=results)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks mike, works like a charm and i understand the concept now as well. Appreciate it!